# HDDs don’t work properly with Dell 6/IR Raid Controller

Tags: hard-drive, raid-1, hardware-raid, dell-poweredge, windows-server-2019

I maintain a Dell PowerEdge T410 (running Windows Server 2019 Essentials) with a *SAS 6/IR* RAID controller configured with a RAID1 of two *Seagate Exos E 7E2 1TB* ([link to exact specs here](https://gzhls.at/blob/ldb/e/6/3/1/5702e233241306cee13d73ba96b66f8bc586.pdf)) HDDs, which should replace the 7 years old Dell/Seagate Constellation ES 500 GB HDDs (SATA 7.2K RPM), which were in an RAID1.

I've created a backup of the Windows Server from the old drives in order to restore it on the new drives (backup size ~100GB).

First, I tried to install a fresh Windows Server 2019. The installation process stopped at 9% without any error.

Second, I've also tried to clone the old drives to the new ones with Clonezilla. After starting with a 10GB/min write speed, the speed continuously diminishes. After 10 minutes of copying it was already at 750 MB/min write speed.

Third, I tried to directly restore with the Windows Server 2019 installation medium from the Windows Backup and got the following error (after 1.5 hours): 0x8078012D. Unfortunately, I found nothing online corresponding to my issue.

I've tested both new drives separately without the raid controller. SMART Values are OK. Expect for one minor issue: UltraDMA CRC Errors (Value: 200, Worst 199), which should mean nothing according to my Google research. I've tried to copy some big files on the drives - worked perfectly for an 140 GB file with a write speed of 180MB/sec. I've also wiped the disks (with CCleaner) in order to see if there is an error while writing on the disks - no error.

In the current raid controller there is also another RAID1 with two WD Gold 1TB HDDs, which works also fine. Also the RAID1 of the old 500GB drives worked fine for the last years.

Does anybody know whether there is a issue with the new hard drives, the raid controller or something else? Should I just try to replace the drives with the same WD Gold, as in the second Raid1 or try to find the error with the new Seagate drives?